# How to validate radio button is selected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

I am trying to validate that the "Never" radio button is selected, or "Date" (with **datepicker**) is selected with a date, hence `:expiry_date`.

`:expires`      is a `string type`.

`:expiry_date`  is a `date type`.

```
      f.input :expires, as: :radio, :collection => ["Never", "Date"]
      f.input :expiry_date, as: :string, :wrapper_html => { :class => "date_picker"}
```

This is my validations so far.

```
  validates :expires,
  inclusion: { in: ["Never", "Date"],
  presence: { message: "none selected"}}
  validates :expiry_date, presence: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations):

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :has_expiry_date

  def has_expiry_date
    if expires == "Date" && !expiry_date.present?
      errors.add(:expiry_date, 'needs to be present if food expires')
    end
  end
end
```